# cerrar app desde notificacion

Tags: java, android, android-studio

quiero terminar con la app el pulsar la notificacion, mi codigo actual lanza una activiti pero quiero directamente finalizar la app

```
private void notificacion (String radio){

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =(NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //int icono = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, i, 0);

    mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Anime Fm 2")
            .setContentText("Reproduciendo "+radio+" en segundo plano")
            //.setVibrate(new long[] {100, 250, 100, 500})
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    if (mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    } else {
        mNotifyMgr.cancel(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: La única forma que se me ocurre que hagas es usando un `BroadcastReceiver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que agregar al tu parte del código donde quieres que se cierre. El método finish().

```
finish().
```

Al crear su Intent:

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);  
i.setAction("fin");  //Agregue una accion
```

En onCreate de su Activity:

```
try {
String s = getIntent().getAction();

if (s.equals("fin")) {
    finish();
}
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

Comment: pero quiero que se cierrre al pulsar la notifiaccion

Comment: Correcto esto cierra la aplicación.

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias